# BlockingCollection, race condition?

Tags: c#, multithreading, blockingcollection

I've implemented a Producer/Consumer pattern using a BlockingCollection however it doesn't seem to be blocking as I expect.

I have one thread receiving Frames from a webcam and adding them to the BlockingCollection

```
private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs) {
    image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    queue.Add(image);
    if (NewFrame != null)
        NewFrame(this, new NewFrameEventArgs(image)); //invoke the event for display
}
```

And in another thread I have a reference to the collection and process the Frames using

```
public void Run() {
    foreach (Bitmap bmp in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
        // process bitmap
```

However, as you can see below it tends to throw an InvalidOperationException telling me the Frame I'm pulling is in use elsewhere.

[img http://i17.photobucket.com/albums/b52/orubap/2012-03-24_020858.png](http://i17.photobucket.com/albums/b52/orubap/2012-03-24_020858.png)

It doesn't always happen straight away but I've noticed it only occurs when the queue is empty or near empty (ie. the consumer is faster than the producer) so I'm guessing it's something to do with the first image added or the last image taken. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Well, it seems you *are* using the image in two places. One is in the consumer of the collection, the other is the event handler. That's most likely your problem. `BlockingCollection` has no knowledge of other things you might be doing, it won't help you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread that executes `video_NewFrame` is using the image when it's passed to the `NewFrame` event handler. Since this is running concurrently with `Run`, there's nothing preventing the two threads from accessing `image` at the same time. (This will only happen when `Run` dequeues the image while the `NewFrame` event handler is processing it, which explains why you see it only when the queue is empty or nearly empty.)

One fix might be to move the call to `NewFrame` *before* `queue.Add(image);` (in `video_NewFrame`). That would ensure that `Run` can't see it until the event handler is finished with it (assuming the event handler doesn't store a reference to it).

Comment: You and svick are right, the issue is the event handler. I had thought the NewFrameEventArgs fires off a copy and not a reference to its subscribers. Whether I added to the queue or fired off NewFrame first, the solution was to make sure I was using a clone so the second operation wasn't using the same reference. Thank you!